# History.SE and Health.SE have identical favicons

Tags: bug, design

Both [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com) and History.SE have the same favicon - the SE blue beta speech bubble, with a capital 'H'. Can we please make them have unique icons?

Comment: I wish I had the power to fulfill this request. However, you folks should be happy I don't, as my artistic skills I'm afraid are quite limited to text editors.

Answer (score 3):

Well fortunately, [Health](//health.stackexchange.com/) is now called [Medical Sciences](//medicalsciences.stackexchange.com). And their icon is changed to `MED`. :)

Comment: Yep. Plus: History is no longer in beta and will soon (yeah, I know…'eventually') get a custom icon anyway.